# Find the maximize of $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $x>0$, $y>0$ and $z>0$ such that $xy+yz+xz=3$. Find a maximize of $$P=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}+\frac{1}{y^2+z^2+1}+\frac{1}{z^2+x^2+1}$$

---

We need to prove $P\le 1$ with $x=y=z=1$

We have: $$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}\le \frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+1\right)\Rightarrow P\le \frac{1}{9}\left(2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)+3\right)$$

Or we prove $$\frac{1}{9}\left(2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)+3\right)\le 1\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\le 3$$

WLOG $x\ge y\ge z\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2}\le \frac{1}{y^2}\le \frac{1}{z^2};xy\ge yz\ge xz$

By Chebyshev's inequality :

$LHS=\left(xy+yz+xz\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}\right)\ge3\left(\dfrac{y}{x}+\dfrac{z}{y}+\dfrac{x}{z}\right)\ge3\cdot 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{y}{x}\cdot\dfrac{z}{y}\cdot\dfrac{x}{z}}=9$

$\Leftrightarrow9\ge\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}\right)^2\Leftrightarrow3\ge\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}$

Is it right? Pls check for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+1)(1+1+z^2)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2+z^2}{(x+y+z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+6}{(x+y+z)^2}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz)}{(x+y+z)^2}=1.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=1$, which says that $1$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Why did you solve it for him? He did not asked for the solution.

Comment: Dear  @john nobody In our forum accepted to write some trying. Sometimes we have no any relation between  this trying and solving of the problem. I just understand this phenomena and I solve these problems.

Comment: Dear Michael I know you just wanted to help and that is OK...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you got wrong direction here:

$$\left(xy+yz+xz\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}\right)\ge3\left(\dfrac{y}{x}+\dfrac{z}{y}+\dfrac{x}{z}\right)\ge3\cdot 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{y}{x}\cdot\dfrac{z}{y}\cdot\dfrac{x}{z}}=9$$

so $$\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}\ge 3$$